# Code-First regenerate files and keep same configuration - abstract class and class names to keep the same

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Whenever I generate my classes using code-first from database **(Add > New Item > ADO.NET Entity Framework > Code First from Database)** approach I need to change the class name all the time:

```
[Table("tableName")]
public abstract partial class MyClassReferencingtableName
```

Also I changed the class to be abstract, and would need to change it everytime that classes are regenerated.

Is there a way to define the configuration mappings between the database and the classes once that whenever I use the code-first approach I just click generate and it will use it's configuration ?

Comment: You might want to be a bit more clear about what you are asking. It actually sounds like you are not doing code-first but database-first.

Comment: @SOfanatic - Actually is code-first from database option, I also think the name is a little contradictory, but it is the option you have when you do: New Item -> ADO.Net Entity Data Model -> Code-first from database.

Comment: I think that option is meant for you to get your code-first solution up and running - if you're continuing to work from your database then you should probably be doing database first.

Comment: @Richard - it makes a lot of sense, so the answer to my question would be "No, there is not a way for updating code first already generated code", Now I just used the database first approach, and using it you can change class Name and make it abstract without futher problems.